# C++ program to count number of objects in a particular Linux directory

Tags: c++, linux, system

I'm attempting to write a program in Linux using C++ that counts the number of files and folders in a user specified directory, but the more I read, the more confused I get. I'm new to C++ and to programming in general, and I understand that I have a big hurdle to vault at the start, but I'm not entirely sure where to start reading on this one. I've read a bit about forking processes and system calls, but if someone were to briefly outline the process I have to go through to achieve this, then I can do more in depth reading on the various functions myself.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `fork`. Although it *is* a fundamental Unix-y system call and lots of material talks about it, don't get the idea that you have to use it for everything. ;)

Comment: The "number of objects in a Linux directory" should include more than files and folders. Just check the `/dev/` directory, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With C++ [Boost.FileSystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm) gives you convenient tools to achieve what you want.

If you want to learn the basic C APIs, take a look at [File System Interface](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-System-Interface.html#File-System-Interface) in the GNU C library manual.

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* want to do it the Linux way, take a look at the `opendir`, `readdir`, and `closedir` system calls. There is an example [here](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=11775&lngWId=3) that is basically the program you are trying to write (it prints contents instead of counting them, though).

If I were you, I would stick with a higher-level library like Georg suggested.

Answer (score 0):

On *nix you can  the C library functions [opendir](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/opendir.html) and [readdir](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/readdir.html)

Basically, call opendir() to get a handle to a directory. Iterate through the entries in that directory with readdir()

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most cross-platform way to do this is with [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/). On UNIX (Linux, Mac OS X, Free BSD, etc.) there are a number of ways to do this. As have been pointed out, [opendir](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/opendir.html), [readdir](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir.html), and [closedir](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/closedir.html) are possibilities. I should point out that, instead of using readdir, it is better to use [readdir_r](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir_r.html) which is reentrant (meaning that it is safe to use concurrently from multiple different threads), whereas the ordinary readdir call is not reentrant (and therefore not guaranteed by the Single UNIX Specification / IEEE Std. 1003.1 a.k.a. POSIX to be threadsafe). Though these may not be the easiest to use and not appropriate for this particular task, for other actions that walk the filesystem, you might also be interested in [nftw](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nftw.html) and [ftw](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ftw.html), which are particularly well suited to acting on subtrees of the filesystem.